# Nested templates in Polymer

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom

I'm trying to use nested templates with polymer but I can not get all the elements that have the class `menu--item__has_submenu`.

The code:

```
<template>
   <nav class="page-nav">
     <button class="menu--link close_menu" on-click="_toggleMenu">
       <div class="menu--icon">
         <br-icons class="nav-btn-icon" icon="br-icons:close"></br-icons>
       </div>
     </button>
     <ul class="menu js-menu">
       <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
         <li class="menu--item menu--item__has_submenu" on-click="_toggleSubmenu">
           <a href="{{item.link}}" class="menu--link" title="{{item.label}}">
             <div class="menu--icon" data-icon="{{item.icon}}">
               <br-icons icon="br-icons:user"></br-icons>
             </div>
             <span class="menu--text">{{item.label}}</span>
           </a>            
           <ul class="submenu">
             <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.submenu}}">
               <li class="submenu--item">
                 <a href="{{item.link}}" class="submenu--link">{{item.label}}</a>
               </li>
             </template>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </template>
     </ul>
   </nav>
 </template>


Polymer({
   is: 'br-nav',
   properties: {
     items: {
       type: Array,
       value: []
     }
   },

   ready: function () {           

   },

   _toggleMenu: function () {
     Polymer.dom(this).classList.toggle('page-nav__opened');
   },

   _toggleSubmenu: function(e){
     console.log(Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('menu--item__has_submenu'));
     //returns empty array
   },

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

I set the `ul` tag with an id and then did the following:

```
_toggleSubmenu: function(e){
   console.log(Polymer.dom(this.$.ulId).querySelectorAll('.menu--item__has_submenu'));
   //returns an array of elements

},
```